# Which one is best book for Topology ( for General Topology)?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, book-recommendation

Which one  is  best book  for Topology (for General Topology)?

Topology  by Dugundji or  Topology  by John L. Kelley?

I have  no any idea regarding these two  books and I have to choose  any one of them. Actually I'm going to start with Topology and I'm confused  now on which one I have to choose first, Dugundji or John L. Kelley?

Comment: Disappointing that you only have those $2$ to choose from. Engelking has the best reputation, but that does not help you if you're not able (or allowed) to use it. I don't know Dugundji but I have a Kelley on my shelf and I find it a bit of a wall of text, and a bit old-fashioned, but it has a solid reputation.

Comment: I prefer Stephen Willard’s *General Topology* to either of those. *Topology*, by James R. Munkres, is also good, though I don’t care for some of his notation. If you must choose between Dugundji and Kelley, I’d go with Dugundji: both are dated and a bit old-fashioned, but it’s more readable. Engelking is more comprehensive than any of these and probably a bit much if one is just starting.

Comment: thanks u sir @BrianM.Scott i will looks  for Engelking as first time i heard this books author name

Comment: @jasmine: You’re welcome. The book is: Ryszard Engelking, *General Topology*, Państwowe Wydawnictwo Naukowe (PWN — Polish Scientific Publishers), Warsaw, 1977.

Comment: Engelking is great if you've already learn the basics and want a good reference to almost all standard facts that Kelley, Dugundji, Willard or Munkres also prove in their own ways. The exercises alone are a great intro to a lot of the research literature and topics (of its time). The Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology is better if you want to go into more modern papers. It depends on what  your purpose is. As a starting text book use Willard, I'd say. It's the most modern.